# How to specify snowflake session parameters in Talend

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I am using Talend to load data from Oracle to Snowflake. I am able to set up the load pipeline, but I wanted to set the query tag as part of the load pipeline so that I can do some analysis based on the tag. However, I could not find any way to specify the query tag along with query statements (`ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG='TALENDLOAD'`) in the load pipeline.

Is it that Talend does not allow to set the session parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first run `ALTER SESSION SET MULTI_STATEMENT_COUNT=0;` as the default value is 1, which allows only one statement in JDBC and ODBC connectors info [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#multi-statement-count)

Then you may pass `ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG='TALENDLOAD'` along with other query statements.